# StateT monad inside Handler in purescript-express

Tags: functional-programming, purescript

I want to persist some data in StateT monad,

Within `Handler` of the `post`(any http method) function I want to modify the data stored in state... but the issue is I can't use State inside Handler...

```
newtype HandlerM a =  HandlerM (Request -> Response -> Effect Unit -> Aff a)

type Handler = HandlerM Unit
```

and type of http methods are as follows,

```
post :: forall r. RoutePattern r => r -> Handler -> App
```

I want to do something like,

```
post "/some/api" $ do 
     S.modify (\s -> s { count = s.+ 1}} ---- modify state with respect to response 
     --- handle request
```

ps: I can use `ref` but is there any way I can use StateT inside Handler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'd have to use a `Ref` for this - `State` doesn't work in situations like this.

If you could plumb it through, what would happen is each request being processed would operate in its own `State`, starting over with the initial value each time.

Comment: Yes, I have to use `Ref` no other way around